# Maximum Matching for Line Graphs

Tags: bipartite-matching

I tried to study the maximum matching for a line-graph , i.e , $L(G)$ of a graph , $G(V,E)$ , from here : 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X97001039

But could not understand it , can anybody explain it in detail .

I understood how to  create the corresponding tree , but after that I could not understand the process of finding the maximum matching .

Comment: "Please explain this paper to me" usually isn't a good fit here.  First, that's a lot to ask.  Our site is designed for question that can be answered in a few paragraphs, not for something that requires a long exposition.  Second, I worry that if you didn't understand the paper, if someone takes the time to write an explanation, you might say you didn't understand that, either.  Third, the balance of effort seems imbalanced.  You haven't shown us what you did understand, what is the first part you don't understand, or articulated a specific question about some specific aspect you don't get.

Comment: It often works better to make questions interesting for others by providing background and summarizing what you do understand, and try to identify some specific question about some specific aspect you don't understand.

Comment: We prefer that you provide a full reference (title, authors, where published, and a link to a freely available PDF if you can find one), so that others who also have a similar question about this paper can find this page by search.

Comment: I am updating it , Sir.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/123741/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61082584/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).